# Use Raspberry's VideoCore IV GPU for chainer model. Requires cupy? cuda?

Tags: raspberry-pi, pose-estimation, chainer, cupy

I am trying to run [Idein/chainer-pose-proposal-net](https://github.com/Idein/chainer-pose-proposal-net) on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+. This is a pose estimation model (specifically Pose Proposal Networks
by Taiki Sekii) in Chainer.

In the README it is suggested that it can use the Raspberry's VideoCore IV GPU to achieve up to 10fps. My problem is that I do not know how to make it use the GPU. What has to be installed?

I looked at [CuPy](https://github.com/cupy/cupy) which would be the way to go if it's a Nvidia GPU and CUDA installed. I could not find an alternative for the Raspberry.

I also had a look at [Actcast](https://actcast.io/) but there is no documentation on how to use it.

```
python3 video.py trained/mobilenetv2_224x224_1.0_mpii/
```

Desired result is to get close to 10fps, but currently without GPU I only get ~0.4fps.

---

**Edit 2019-05-28:**

In the meantime tried the following. Unfortunately I am still unable to achieve the desired frame rate:

- I successfully installed [QMKL](https://github.com/Idein/qmkl) with all dependencies [py-videocore](https://github.com/nineties/py-videocore) etc.
- I installed [VC4CL](https://github.com/doe300/VC4CL) OpenCL 1.2 standard for the VideoCore IV GPU
- I found [clpy](https://github.com/fixstars/clpy) which is a is CuPy but using OpenCL backend. I successfully installed and tested it and import it, but I do not get improved performance.

Comment: Have you got any success with that? Trying to do the same.